# Prompt input validation

Tags: node.js, validation, botframework

The context is MS Bot Framework on Node. I need to custom validate an input from a Prompt.text or Prompt.Number. I have been taking a look at examples and docs. I have implemented a quick example with `DialogAction.validatePrompt()`, which works ok but has the problem that I cannot (or at least I don't know how) customize the message in case the validation fails.

The validation could fail for many reasons and it would be great to be able to choose a response message based on the failure reason.

Also I have seen the basics-custom-prompt example in: `(https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node/examples/basics-customPrompt)` and it uses and `IntentDialog` to get the desired behavior. It also mentions it is a replacement for the basics-validatedPrompt example.

My questions are:

- Which one is recommend to use, validatedPrompt or the IntentDialog
  approach?
- Is the `validatedPrompt()` going to be deprecated?
- Does the `validatedPrompt()` provide a mechanism for custom message?

Comment: Why not use a choice prompt? This way your users will know what options are available, and you can take advantage of the built-in validation of the choice prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Bot Framework Version 4 Prompt Validation Example link is specified in below :

> https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/10.prompt-validations

For Proper Text Prompt Validation is you create separate file which perform validation task
Code: **namePrompt/index.js**

```
const { TextPrompt } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');

module.exports.NamePrompt = class NamePrompt extends TextPrompt {
    constructor(dialogId) {
        super(dialogId, async (prompt) => {
            if (!prompt.recognized.succeeded) {
                await prompt.context.sendActivity('Please tell me your name.');
                return false;
            } else {
                const value = prompt.recognized.value;
                if (value.length < 1) {
                    await prompt.context.sendActivity('Your name has to include at least one character.');
                    return false;
                } else if (value.length > 50) {
                    await prompt.context.sendActivity(`Sorry, but I can only handle names of up to 50 characters. Yours was ${ value.length }.`);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Now inside your current dialog you can import above file:

```
const { NamePrompt } = require('../../prompts/namePrompt');
const GET_NAME_PROMPT = 'namePrompt';
this.addDialog(new NamePrompt(GET_NAME_PROMPT));
```

inside your dialog step you can prompt such like this:

```
async promptForName(step) {
           return await step.prompt(GET_NAME_PROMPT, `What is your name, human?`);

}
```